# I have trouble with my S3 index and error file path using terraform, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform-provider-aws

Am I specifying the correct file path to my index and error document?

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "travel_agency" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.id

  index_document {
    suffix = "/travel-agency-html-template/index.html"
  }

  error_document {
    key = "/travel-agency-html-template/404.html"
  }
}
```

This is because I keep getting the below error

`Error: error creating S3 bucket (my-test-bucket-for-cloudfront) website configuration: InvalidArgument: The IndexDocument Suffix is not well formed`

Comment: Remove the leading slashes.

Comment: Amazing, it worked! But one other thing, as I visited the website endpoint, I still received a `404 Not Found`